# Good output for first language

Tags: c, terminal, programming-languages, executable

I have built a compiler for my new programming language. It works perfectly. I am onto the last part. I need to put it into a runnable format (an executable). I was looking at the mach-o format (I am runnning on osx), but it is not well documented and I am not that advanced. So my question is:

What is a good output for my first compiler?

P.S. I would really like to be able to run my program in terminal

Comment: I'd suggest you go to generating LLVM code and let the LLVM infrastructure generate code for each specific architecture.

Comment: If you don't have it in an executable format, how do you know it works 'perfectly'? Or at all?

Comment: @MikeW I have Performed tests as I built the compiler. When I said it worked "Perfectly", I meant that it performs syntatic analysis, and lexical analysis as it should

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac Is there any documentation on this? Or how to do it?

Comment: LLVM assembly is not trivial: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html You might consider targeting a simple C subset that closely matches your internal representation first. Get that right, get your programs running and then decide if you want to tackle assembly code or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [TAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_address_code) as an output of your compiler. [TAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_address_code) is a context free language, which means it can easily be converted to assembly by a simple script. It is widely used by compilers to optimize the intermediate code, before it is translated to a processor specific assembly language and being optimized to the corresponding processor architecture.
If I'm not wrong, there are several types of TAC code, and you will need to find which one suits you better. I remember having used it as an output of my compiler in the compiler course of my graduation, because I could then run a python script which would translate it into x86 assembly